# Retrieving facebook share count via api

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to get like counts from facebook's api. If you access this url http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.yahoo.com

the like_count is currently around **422493**. But if I run this jQuery script([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2tsB/)) it displays **1318998**. Is there something wrong with this script?

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&urls=http://www.yahoo.com;",
    dataType: "xml"
}).done(function(data) {
    var $xml = $(data),
        $title = $xml.find("like_count");
    $('#fbshare').text($title.text());
});           
</script>

<div id="fbshare"></div>
```

API is referenced from here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2009/10/26/extending-facebook-share/

Comment: The difference is the `;` at the end of the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this FQL query,Hope this would help.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%22www.yahoo.com%22

Comment: whats the difference?

Comment: Facebook is deprecating the REST API
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/616/

It would be better to choose Graph API/FQL methods.

Comment: I see. I will use this Thank you!