# How to get Share_count and like_count in GraphAPI2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Getting notification from FB, they will remove FQL inthe later release after 2.0 which is expect to be on 2016.

Currently my Apps are using FQL to get the like_count and share_count. I hope someone can share with me how to achieve this in GraphAPI2.0 because in GraphAPI, I only able to retrieve the total count.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27

```
<fql_query_response list="true"><link_stat>
<url>http://www.google.com</url>
<share_count>5860640</share_count>
<like_count>1446662</like_count>
<comment_count>1775201</comment_count>
<total_count>9082503</total_count>
<click_count>265614</click_count>
</link_stat></fql_query_response>
```

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.google.com

```
{
   "id": "http://www.google.com",
   "shares": 9082503
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627566/using-graph-api-instead-of-fql-for-facebook

Answer (score 1):

The more up to date way of using your FQL would be

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url,%20share_count,%20like_count,%20comment_count,%20total_count,%20click_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27http://www.google.com%27
```

If you'd like to use the old (deprecated, but still working) `api.facebook.com` endpoint, try

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/links.getStats?urls=http://www.google.com&format=json
```

This doesn't employ FQL at all, but you can't be sure how long this works. It's not even in their docs anymore. FQL will be around 2 years from the moment Facebook announces the successor of the Graph API v2.0, so I would recommend go go along with the first suggestion.

**Graph API v2.0 doesn't have an endpoint IMHO to generate URL sharing stats other than the FQL method.**

Comment: The REST API you're referring to here (api.facebook.com) is also deprecated

Comment: I know, and I wrote that: `...the old (deprecated, but still working) api.facebook.com...`

Comment: But using the methods in your answer doesn't solve the OP's question, of how to fetch that data using Graph API version 2.0 or higher

Comment: I think it does, because Graph API v2.0 doesn't have any other method to generate URL share stats, or do you as FB employee have a better/other solution? If so, I think I'm not the only one who'd be glad to hear :-)

Comment: Thanks Tobi, I think now we have no choice but to wait for FB came out with a solution to achieve this.

Comment: Why? You can use FQL for at least another two years... Like I said, I would only migrate the the `graph.facebook.com` endpoint if I were you